# resuable validator for multiple cases

Tags: validation, angular, custom-validators, angular-reactive-forms

I made a date validator. It validates existing dates. I need multiple date validator with other restrictions, for ex : a max date validator that won't let the user put in a future date or a date validator that only takes past dates. This is my current validator.

```
    export function dateValidator(group) {

  const {day, month, year} = group.value;
  const fullDate = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
  const dobPattern = /^(\d{1,2})[-\/](\d{1,2})[-\/](\d{4})$/;
  const isStringValid = dobPattern.test(fullDate);

  let isValid = false;

  if (isStringValid) {
    const intDay = Number(day);
    const intMonth = Number(month);
    const intYear = Number(year);
    const jsMonth = intMonth - 1;
    const date = new Date(intYear, jsMonth, intDay);
    isValid = (date.getFullYear() === intYear && date.getMonth() === jsMonth && date.getDate() === intDay ;
  }

  return isValid ? null : { invalid: 'Invalid date' };
};
```

How can I restrict the user from putting in future dates.
I used this code with the following line:

```
    isValid = (date.getFullYear() === intYear && date.getMonth() === jsMonth && date.getDate() === intDay ;
```

But I wonder if there is an easier way without having to copy and past this code over and over again to make small restrictions to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dateValidator()` function should be a **function factory** (i.e. *a function that returns a function*) instead of a function that returns the error directly:

```ts
export function dateValidator(maxDate: string): ValidatorFn {
  // Return a validator function.
  return (group: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {
    // Re-use your existing validation code here and return the error if any.
    // Optionally, use the `maxDate` param to customize the validation:
    // entered dates should not go beyond `maxDate`.
  };
}
```

As you can see, you can customize the validator function by passing parameters to the function factory. In my example, I used a `maxDate` parameter to indicate the furthest date in time that the validator should allow.

In your **form model**, use this validator by calling the factory with the appropriate value, e.g. :

```ts
this.myForm = fb.group({
  'date': ['', [Validators.required(), dateValidator('02/20/2017')]]
});
```

You can see another example of a function factory for a validator in the doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#custom-validation

Comment: Does that mean I have to copy and paste the code for multiple validators? I'm new to this.

Comment: No. If you organize your code properly, there shouldn't be a need for copy/pasting. Just create ONE `dateValidator` function factory like I explained, with all the parameters you need to customize how it works (like `maxDate` in my example). Then use that one validator in all the fields where it's needed, you'll probably have to pass different parameters every time you use the validator.